# Storing variable changes during a switch [Java]

Tags: java, android

I am currently in the process of making a calculator for Android (I am not using any tutorials) and am running into an issue.

I have this:

```
public void buttonOnClick(View v){

   int operation;

   switch (v.getId()){
      case R.id.one:
          numberBox.append("1");
          break;
      case R.id.two:
          numberBox.append("2");
          break;
      case R.id.plus:
          operation=1;
          break;
      case R.id.eq:
          if (operation == 1){
              // Print value
          }
      break;
      default:
          break;
    }

}
```

Note that this is not the exact code, it is just a mockup.

The problem is, with the scope of the case, when the operation is set to 1, it is not set publicly and when I go to read it in the equals case, it is set back to 0.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `operation` is a local variable, so every time you enter the method it's going to be initialized as a new variable and have nothing to do with what `operation` was set to last time. I would recommend having some object that stores what the current operation is and passing that object to the method, then reading/writing the variable using that object.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I even missed that. Is it a bad idea to just leave 'operation' a public variable outside of the buttonClick method?

Comment: I wasn't sure if your setup would allow you to pass in an object so I left that as a comment instead of an answer. Since it fixed your problem, I post it as an answer now. You're welcome!

Comment: Nevermind, Meirav's answer is just as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be new in Java or any other programming language:

local variables are only used in the method they are declared in.
Whenever you go out of the method the variable is destroyed as well as its value.

So each time you enter a new variable is initialized.

To make this work just create a global class variable and use it or

Pass an object to the method that holds some int variable : the current operation, then read/write the variable using that object.

Comment: Thank you. It's been a while since I have done some actual programming, so I completely forgot to just leave it a global variable. 

Can you give me an example of creating an object which holds the current operation and passing that to the method?

Comment: Look at my other answer

Answer (score 0):

In your case its better to use a global class variable:

```
public class MyClass {
        int operation;

        public int getOperation() {
            return operation;
        }

        public void setOperation(int value) {
            this.operation = value;
        }

        .....
```

### THEN:

```
....

    public void buttonOnClick(View v){

    ...

    case R.id.plus:
              this.operation = 1;
              break;
          case R.id.eq:
              if (this.operation == 1){
                  // Print value
              }
          break;

    .....
```